# Limit read access to a subtree to a certain role in Sitecore

Tags: security, roles, sitecore

I've been struggling with this off and on for months, and it may be non-trivial to answer.

What is the easiest way to limit public access to an item and its subitems to members of a single role? (Editors still need to be able to edit the item.)

e.g. There's a role, `extranet/clubmember`, and items,

```
- Clubhouse
 | - Items
 | - Inside
 | - Clubhouse
```

And I want `extranet/clubmember` members to be able to read the items and subitems, sitecore/* members (Or, say, sitecore/editor) to have edit access, and everyone else (in default and extranet domains) to be denied.

Second, does this solution still work with a custom role and membership providers for extranet? Why or why not, or what methods do I need to implement? I recall from earlier experiments that my custom role provider seems to affect Inheritance permissions in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the following:

- uncheck Inherit for Everyone (the global one) to Clubhouse root
- explicitly allow Read for extranet\clubmember to Clubhouse root
- explicitly allow Read/Write for sitecore\Everyone to Clubhouse root

Explicit assignments always win. So, that scheme should have the effect you expect.

Comment: I think I tried this with extranet/Everyone instead of Everyone and it didn't work for some reason, but this works.

Comment: The key point here is extranet\Everyone is a "local" everyone, in scope if extranet domain, while Everyone is a global one, which includes all local everyones as well. Good to know if worked for you.